# Create JSON key&value dynamically from raw text file

Tags: python, json, dynamic

I'm trying to make a program that allow user to format their raw files to JSON format dynamically.
Currently, I managed to make a text file to JSON format with hard-coded value/index. But what i want is letting user to create their own value and extract certain strings from the raw files to json format. Letting user to customize their own key and value to be convert
Is there anyway to achieve my goal? Can it be done with ReGex ? *Scenario: User upload their text file and they get to choose which key and what string to be store then convert to json format*

**Sample files that i want to extract:**  *Other user may upload other files too*

```
13-May-2020 14:19:14;176039082005130240000000  SYNC RotaryRight_1002110 MeasureATI;RotKnob_EMERGENCY-EXIT
13-May-2020 14:19:29;176039082005130240000000  SYNC RotaryRight_1003010 Start Communication_ERROR:Key in Position 'MANUAL'
13-May-2020 14:19:29;176039082005130240000000  SYNC RotaryLeft_1002010 Start Communication_ERROR:Key in Position 'MANUAL'
13-May-2020 14:31:18;176039082005130321000000  SYNC RotaryRight_1002110 MeasureATI;RotKnob_EMERGENCY-EXIT
13-May-2020 14:41:52;176039082005130291000000  SYNC RotaryRight_1002110 MeasureATI;RotKnob_EMERGENCY-EXIT
13-May-2020 14:49:58;176039082005130301000000  SYNC RotaryRight_1002110 MeasureATI;RotKnob_EMERGENCY-EXIT
```

**Illustration :**
[image]

**My hard-coded code:**

```
    for content in data2:
        splitted_line = content.split(" ")
        print(splitted_line)
        file_data = {}
        file_data["Date"] = splitted_line[0]
        time_and_code = splitted_line[1].split(";")
        file_data["Time"] = time_and_code[0]
        file_data["Code"] = time_and_code[1]
        file_data["Status"] = splitted_line[3]
        file_data["Message"] = " ".join(splitted_line[4:])
        # output to JSON

        global tmp
        tmp = json.dumps(file_data, ensure_ascii=False, indent="\t")
        reviewjson.insert(END, tmp)
```

**Result**

```
{
'Date':  '13-May-2020',
'Time': ' 12:49:35',
'Code': ' 176036072005120136000000'
'Sync Status': 'SYNC'
' Message': ' RotaryRight_1001010 MOV P1 -> Park Position_BUSY'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of your question is correct, then you don't actually need regex. You need something called [list slice](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). In your case you wouldn't use split then.

```py
file_data["key1"] = content[0:10]
file_data["key2"] = content[11:20]
file_data["key3"] = content[25:] if content[20:24] == "SYNC" else ""
```

To allow user input

```py
number_of_keys = int(intput("Enter number of expected keys: "))
st = "YOUR STRING TO PARSE TO DICT"
result = {}
for key_idx in range(number_of_keys):
    start_idx = int(input("Enter starting index: "))
    end_idx = int(input("Enter end index: "))
    key_name = input("Enter key name: ")
    result[key_name] = st[start_idx:end_idx]
print(result)
```

This is a basic example, but you can build something on top of that

Comment: Hi thanks for ur replied. But this is hard coded right? what i need is letting user to customize their own key and value to be convert

Comment: You need to use variables then, like for example reading from `input`. If the strings are varying length, then user would have to specify regex, which is something that probably should be avoided. I'll edit the answer to give a bit of an example for the first case

Comment: Thanks ! , i will try to work with your method. thanks again for enlighten me haha

Comment: But if strings that are varying length, then should use regex instead?

Comment: Yes, but then user would have to specify regex. It's not as simple, since it'd have to handle exceptions